# Dealing with plagiarism

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

It's happened to me twice already in the last couple of days (once here and once on one of the other sites) and I've also seen it on questions where I have not been involved, that there are guys that simply copy answers over, maybe change like a letter or so and paste it, then what happens is they get accepted because their answer is the newest has more visibility and the questioner doesn't really seem to care. As I've pointed out before, building rep in this site is not an easy task (at least not honestly).

Could there be a "Duplicate answer" flag that will prioritize precedence? so the rightful answerer can get their rep?

Can we do something about these copy pasters that take the someone else's credit?

Comment: you can flag if latter answer is just exact copy of older

Comment: I agree, didn't think of the term plagiarism until after reading some responses

Comment: Where is my duplicate post comment gone ?

Comment: In this cases should I delete the question? keep flagging it? or just let it be?

Answer (score 8):

If you think there's been genuine plagiarism, then flagging for moderator attention is warranted. Just click the `flag` link underneath your answer, or the answer you believe copied yours, and select "other" under "it needs ♦ moderator attention".

Consider, though, the possibility that the duplication was unintentional. There's only so many ways to [write a range check](http://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/), after all.