# How to handle several instances of unattributed/plagiarized answers

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, attribution, plagiarism

What is the best way to handle instances where there are many seemingly copy-and-pasted answers from other answers that lack proper attribution? There have been [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172108/dealing-with-plagiarism) [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq) [dealing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122056/should-i-flag-plagiarism-for-moderator-attention) with using answers from other people in the community, but I am looking for some "proper procedure" to deal with answers that span multiple questions, through multiple users rather than just one answer by one user. To what extent would leaving comments to each user, or adding to the already heavy moderator flag load, be appropriate?

To cite some specific examples, all relating to handling different screen sizes between 3.5" and 4" iOS devices (in chronological order by the date the question was asked, but not necessarily the date the answer was posted):

1. [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution/)

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16275958/697560 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447113/697560 (2)
2. [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587966/697560 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502356/697560 (1)
3. [Display different xib files based on iPhone screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267736/display-different-xib-files-based-on-iphone-screen-size/)

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14273604/697560 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502356/697560 (1)
4. [iPhone simulator does not show iphone 5 compatible image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356306/iphone-simulator-does-not-show-iphone-5-compatible-image/)

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357425/697560 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357425/697560 (1, with addition)
5. [finding difference iphone 4s and 5 working wrongly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225968/finding-difference-iphone-4s-and-5-working-wrongly/)

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226059/697560 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357425/697560 (1)
6. [Use two different nib files for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173005/xcode-ios-how-do-you-make-two-different-xib-files-for-iphone-4-and-iphone-5/)

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19181118/697560 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502356/697560 (1, with slight modification)
   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173468/697560, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173089/697560 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447113/697560 (2)

I tried to stick with answers that were pretty clearly copies of another, but there are others that are likely the same.

How should I handle cases like this where I find more than just a "one off" duplication of answers? As a side note, a few of these could possibly be merged or closed as duplicates (1 and 2; 3 and 6), but the others are different questions -- does this have any bearing on the correct course of action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flags work just fine in my experience:

[image]

I've just recently flagged two different users' posts as being plagiarized from a third answer myself.